# smartd Mailing with sendmail

Tags: windows, monitoring, sendmail, hard-drive

first of all i'm sorry for my english.

I'm trying to monitor the hard drives of a lot of Windows machines, and i've seen that can be done with smartd. I've read the man page and i've seen that is possible to sent a mail when an error occurs. I've done some test, searching info in google... but i can't make it work, the smartd daemon don't run the mail program.

I've tested with this in smartd.conf:

```
DEVICESCAN
/dev/hda -m UserName@SomeHost.com -M test -M exec c:\sendmail.cmd
```

and sendmail.cmd is a test script with a simple line:

```
"C:\sendEmail.exe" -f UserName@SomeHost.com -m "Hi There" -l c:\log.log -t UserName@SomeHost.com -s SomeHost.com -xu UserName@SomeHost.com -xp PassWord
```

The cmd script works perfect, but i don't know why smartd dont run that script...

Even I've tried with a hybrid:

```
/dev/hda -m UserName@SomeHost.com -M test -M exec "C:\sendEmail.exe" -f UserName@SomeHost.com -m "Hi There" -l c:\log.log -t UserName@SomeHost.com -s SomeHost.com -xu UserName@SomeHost.com -xp PassWord
```

but don't works too.

The Windows log shows how smartd daemon start and run "DEVICESCAN" command, but nothing about the other line.
I've tested with "smartctl -a /dev/hda" and shows the drive info.

What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed... the problem is "DEVICESCAN". If you run that command all others are ignored. Even i've found an installer to install in a lot of PC's silently and configured.